# What is an RSA subkey?

Tags: gnupg

GPG wants me to enter two sizes: a keysize, and a subkey keysize.  What is the difference?

Answer (score 2):

The subkey is a second (RSA) key specific to one purpose. Normally it is used for decryption.

The idea behind it is that the lifetime of that key might be shorter so you can change it more often. The master key then is used mostly for key attestation purposes.

This also helps with security: you don't want to use the same RSA key for signature and decryption. If you have subkeys for decryption and signature, you could even keep the master key offline.

Answer (score 0):

I asked on IRC, and apparently the master key is used to sign the subkey.  The idea is that you can keep the master key in a relatively safe place, and use the subkey day to day.